# Where can I get ubuntu in german

Tags: installation, localization

I am German. I would like to know where I can get a German version of Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can download Ubuntu [here](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop).

During the install you will be asked what language you would like to install Ubuntu in.

***Ubuntu Installer***

[image]

Even if you somehow manage to mess that up you can always fix that later.

Go to '*System Settings*' >>> '*User Account*' >>> *'Language*

***Settings***

[image]